# Understanding text sizing quirks in CSS for responsive design

Tags: css, responsive, font-size

I'm trying to understand why some texts gets smaller as the screen size gets smaller and other texts with seemingly same style stays the same.

I am trying to make my own navigation bar, and I want my text to stay the same size as the screen gets smaller (like how a bootstrap navbar does), but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. I check the source and I don't understand what attributes to use.

For example, I have two pieces of HTML that are almost the same, but the text sizing behavior is vastly different and I have no idea why.

With no styles, here's a body with text that stays the same size as the screen size decreases:

```
    <body>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore</p>
        <h2>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</h2>
    </body>
```

If I remove one of the paragraphs, or even just the `h2`, the text now becomes smaller as the screen size decreases, why is that?

Here are two codepens that shows the behavior I'm talking about. If you change the screen size using Chrome's device toolbar to test responsive design, you see that these two differents pieces of code shows text resizing to be behaving differently. Altough, if you only resize the browser itself and not use the Chrome's device toolbar, they behave the same? So maybe you can see how I'm getting confused:
https://codepen.io/mhlroy/pen/oVoyeN
https://codepen.io/mhlroy/pen/eXeKxX

Here's an example of a navigation bar I'm trying to have the text stay the same size as the screen size decreases, I want it to stay the same and I'll make the necessary adjustments myself with media queries and make the menu become an hamburger menu for example:
https://codepen.io/mhlroy/pen/OqOEGO

All I want is for the text to stay the same size. I've seen some people mention using `vh` for the `font-size`. And I suppose I could use that, but trying it right now seems to make the text size go bigger as the screen size decreases, so I'm still not sure.

Any help shedding some light on this will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: I can see no difference on the codepen links, both links do the same font "shrink" behaviour. But I don't think the text is actually shrinking, it looks like it's just the browser zooming out to fit the content on the viewport. Read about the meta tag to configure how the viewport should behave https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: That makes sense! It's probably the browser zomming out like you said that would explain the text shrinking, but I still don't understand why they behave differently in my two codepen, I'm not sure why it doesn't for you. Here are screenshots of what happens for me: 
https://i.imgur.com/wLLtMYv.png
https://i.imgur.com/n1giokY.png

Though I tested it on Firefox and both codepen behave the same.. The texts don't shrink.

Comment: Note that the meta tag for the viewport config moves INSIDE the body tag on the pen after rendering, I don't think it works properlly on codepen with an edit view. Do you see the same behaviour using a plain html file? If you change the view to full view mode it works just fine, it's just some bug with chrome on codepen I guess.

Comment: Yes it actually did it with a plain html file opened with the browser, that's how I was testing it before. Looks like it worked fine on Firefox though and not Chrome. Since putting in the viewport meta tag though, it works as I expected and doesn't do that zooming out thing. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As [arieljuod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1430810/arieljuod) mentioned in the comments of my initial question, putting in
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>` in the `head` fixes my issue.
Now it works more consistently and as I personally expected it, which is to not have the page be zoomed out when the screen size changes.

Answer (score 0):

The very first thing I would tell you is to be aware which sizing units are relative and which are fixed. Sizing your text in `vh` is saying make my text x percentage of the height of the screen. So of course when the screen changes height the text size changes. You should be using a unit that is not relative to the screen size. Options include but are not limited to sizing in pixels(`px`) or rems(`rem`). `rem` is a relative unit but it is relative to the root (`body`) font-size and only changes if that changes. Hope that helps!